# Changing title on a new cmd window

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have this batch file script.
It runs multiple instances of the same program with slightly different settings.
*The program isn't notepad btw and the parameters aren't those, it's just here to make it clearer.*

```
timeout /t 0
start cmd /k "title My Title 1 & cd C:\Windows && C: & notepad -noforcemparms & echo note1"
timeout /t 5
start cmd /k "title My Title 2 & cd C:\Windows && C: & notepad -noforcemaccel & echo note2"
timeout /t 5
start cmd /k "title My Title 3 & cd C:\Windows && C: & notepad -noforcemspd -noforcemaccel & echo note3"
```

The issue is that the title of the window becomes ***"My Title 1 - notepad -noforcemparms"***.
What I expected was the window to only be ***"My Title 1"***.

**The reason I need this in batch:**
I have this in powershell, and it changes the title properly, but due to some policies I'm unable to run the ps script on the machine I need it to run on. So I had to convert those to batch.

Is it even possible to change the title like that in batch?

Comment: `start "My Title 1" /k "cd C:\Windows && C: & notepad -noforcemparms & echo note1"`

Comment: See [Start - Start a program - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill it's still the same, the "-notepad" part is still added in the title while it's running

Comment: I don't think it's possible in cmd

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
start "My Title 3" cmd /k cd /d C:\Windows & notepad -noforcemparms & echo note3
```

The `notepad` command here doesn't make sense, but I suppose it's only for
illustration.

Answer (score 0):

> ## It's a simple question...
>
> *Is it even possible to change the title like that in batch?*
>
> - The answer is **[no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39033389)**

---

- Take a good look at **[@Ndir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6733791/ndlr)** **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021975/changing-title-of-an-application-when-launching-from-command-prompt)**

---

> ***[Changing title of an application when launching from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39021975/changing-title-of-an-application-when-launching-from-command-prompt)***
> ‍  <sup>**Note:** linked to question 39021975 on StackOverflow</sup>
> ‍
> *You need to make a program to do this.*
> ‍
> *You need to call the Windows' API. This is how to make a title bar changing program.*
> ‍
> *Create a file using notepad and call it SetText.bas. Store it on your desktop.*
> ‍
> Paste this into it.
> ‍
>
> ```
> Imports System
> Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
> Imports Microsoft.Win32
> ‍    
> Public Module MyApplication  
> ‍
> Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
> Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
> ‍   
> Sub Main()
>   On Error Resume Next
>   Dim CmdLine As String
>   Dim Ret as Long
>   Dim A() as String
>   Dim hwindows as long
>   ‍ 
>   CmdLine = Command()
>   If Left(CmdLine, 2) = "/?" Then
>      MsgBox("Usage:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "ChangeTitleBar Oldname NewName")
>   Else
>      A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(34), -1, vbBinaryCompare)
>      hwindows = FindWindow(vbNullString, A(1))
>      Ret = SetWindowText(hwindows, A(3))    
>   End If
>    ̹
> End Sub
> End Module
> ```
>
> *Then type in a command prompt window.*
> ‍
>
> ```
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%userprofile%\desktop\SetText.exe" "%userprofile%\desktop\settext.bas" /verbose
> ```
>
> ‍
> *A program has been created on your desktop called settext.exe. To use*
> ‍
>
> ```
> "%userprofile%\desktop\settext" "Untitled - Notepad" "A Renamed Notepad"
> ```